# Upper Half "Plane" not diffeomorphic to the whole plane

Tags: differential-geometry

maybe the title isnt the best but I have the following excercise, lets define

$$\cal{H}^n = [0,\infty)^n$$

I have to proove that an open set in $\mathcal{H}^n$  in general is not diffeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I understand the idea of the proof but I don't know how to write it.

My attempt of a solution:

I have the following theorem: Given an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and an arbitrary set $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if there is a diffeomorphism $f:U\rightarrow V$ then $V$ is open.

if $V$ is a subset of $(0,\infty)^n$ there is no problem because $V$ will be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, if $V$ intersects one of the axis then $V$ wont be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we get a contradiction.

Is this right? is there a better way to write it?

Comment: Are you allowed to use algebraic topology?  For now, that is the only proof I can think of.

Comment: whoa... I don't think so but I'm interested in that proof

Comment: I think the idea must be to see what the point $0$ in $\mathcal H$ maps to in $\mathbb R^n$.  Suppose it maps to $x$.  Then locally around $x$, the inverse of the diffeomorphism is close to linear.  But if it is close to linear, how can it map to a neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: You say you understand the idea of the proof. What is that idea?

Comment: The question seemed to change since I last read it.  It might be that I misread it.  But it says it was edited.  So maybe I didn't.

Comment: yes i forgot that they were arbitrary open sets, sorry about that

Comment: I think that nicvsgodzilla has the right idea.  But saying that $V$ is not open in $\mathbb R^n$ doesn't clinch it.  Because we are only interested in $V$ with respect to $\mathcal H^n$.

Comment: my point is that if $V$ intersects one of the axis then $V$ is open in $\cal{H}^n$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^n$, by the theorem there is no diffeomorphism between $V$ and an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to pick a point on $V$ that has one of its coordinates zero.  Now if there is a diffeomorphism from that point to an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ - well, you know that map has a derivative, and that is an $n\times n$ matrix that is invertible.  So locally it is almost linear, and so is its inverse.  But a map that is almost linear cannot map an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ to the point we started with.

Let's make it more rigorous.  So let $f:U \to V$ be the purported map, and suppose $f(x_0) = y_0$ where $y_0$ has one of its coordinates equal to zero.  Let $L$ be the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$.  By applying $L$ to $U$, without loss of generality we can assume $L$ is the identity map.  Now there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x) = y_0 + (x-x_0) + g(x-x_0)$ where $|g(x-x_0)| \le |x-x_0|/10$ if $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$.  (This follows from the definition of being differentiable.)

So now consider $x_0$ with one of the coordinates having plus or minus $\epsilon/2$ added to it.  One of those $2n$ points must map to a point outside of $\mathcal H^n$.